# Code::Blocks build from bash

Tags: codeblocks, travis-ci

I'm developing a C++ application in Code::Blocks.
My program has a few dependencies and has to run under Linux and Windows, this is why
I use Code::Blocks.

Now I'd like to include Travis CI for testing the builds.
On the Travis server, where I have no X11, I won't be able to run Code::Blocks. How can I build my project without Code::Blocks. (Is there a possibility to create "a Makefile" out of the `.cbp`-file?

This page [(Code::Blocks Wiki)](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_command_line_arguments) mentions there is a `--build` flag, but you need Code::Blocks & X11. Is there a server way without X11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **cbp2make** [(C::B Forum entry)](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13675.0).
It is quite simple

```
cbp2make -in project.cbp -out Makefile
```

and it worked immediatly, even with a more complex configuration
than a simple command line project in Code::Blocks.

It also generates the same build targets as in Code::Blocks. For example `make Release` would work.

[The debian package list](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/cbp2make) shows only a few dependencies, so X11 is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run anything which require X11 on Travis, and as far as I know, there is no way to launch a build using Code::Blocks without requiring X11.

The best choice would be to set up your project differently, for example using a Makefile. You will be able to configure Code::Blocks to use your Makefile and also to build on Travis using the *make* command.

You can also consider using [CMake](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) (especially if you are not familiar with Makefile syntax, but not only). This will let you configure your project in a more high level way (compared to a Makefile), and then you will be able to generate a Makefile or a project for the IDE of your choice.

Comment: I had to use Code::Blocks because of a school project, where I had to work with 2 absolute C++ Newbies, it had to be easy and clickable, and we had some dependencies, too, which made it even more difficult for them.

Comment: So in your case, CMake seems to really be a good choice: you can set-up everything for CMake (including *dependencies*); and then, you and your friends only need to run CMake choosing Codeblocks as target IDE and *you will have a CodeBlocks projet*. For Travis, you will run the command line version of CMake choosing Makefile instead of Codeblocks and *you will be able to build your project on Travis using **make***.
And I don't think doing this bypass your constraint of using CodeBlocks (but it is my opinion).