# X11 forwarding in C#

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, codeblocks, x11

I am trying to write a C# application that connects to a remote Linux PC and compiles a C++ project with Code::Blocks. I plan to call Code::blocks by sending the SSH command:

```
codeblocks --rebuild myworkspace.workspace
```

This command works if I run it from a terminal on the Linux computer, but it doesn't work when called through my C# application with SSH.NET, because Code::Blocks wants to open the build log as an X window. Is there a way to handle/show the build log window through X11 forwarding and effectively provide Code::Blocks with a console that has X window support?

There seems to be a lot of information around about X11 forwarding though Putty etc, or between multiple Linux systems, and I found a description of how to do this with JSch in Java from a Windows PC (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/X11Forwarding.java.html) but I can't find any information on X11 forwarding programmatically with .NET languages. For example, how can I write a C# program that calls and displays xclock from a remote PC?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'd consider using a tool like [`cbp2make`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386335/codeblocks-build-from-bash) to convert the codeblocks workspace config file into a `Makefile`, and then building that with just make rather than trying to get X11 forwarding working via `C#`, which will still require an X server on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Petesh. I had wondered if I just have to accept that I'll need to convert the CB project in to something else. I'll take a look.